# htaccess conditional redirect to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i'm trying to redirect to https all visitors except my internal networks 192.168.x and 10.x

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=(192\.168\.$|10\.$)
RewriteRule (.*) https:/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and something is wrong here since isn't working, connecting from internal network it still redirect me to https

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !/^(192\.168\.$|10\.)$/`

Comment: Thansk but isn't working it still redirects me to https

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !/^(192\.168\.|10\.)/`, if it works; I'll add it as an official answer